# Print batch command to file but not console

Tags: batch-file, logging

Is there anyway i can print the command being executed and result of the command in batch to a file but not the console.

**Examples:**

`ls C:\Temp`

I want to print `ls C:\Temp` and result of this command to log file but not on console

`call :function "Argument 1"`

I want to print `call :function "Argument 1"` and result of this command to log file but not on console

`call perl hey.pl`

I want to print `call perl hey.pl` and result of this command to log file but not on console

Comment: https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-redirection.html

Answer (score 0):

```
command > output.txt
```

Will create an output file "output.txt" (You can also use ".log"). If such a file exists, it will overwrite it.

```
command >> output.txt
```

Will also create an output file, but it will append to it (Useful when you're in a loop and want to append the results of all of the iterations).

Answer (score 0):

Create your batch file, e.g. `C:\YourDir\YourBatch.cmd`, making sure that you have **not** turned `Echo Off`.

At your Command prompt run the batch file.

Either by navigating to the holding path:

```
CD /D "C:\YourDir"
```

then invoking

```
"YourBatch.cmd">"Output.log"
```

or just run it directly with:

```
"C:\YourDir\YourBatch.cmd">"C:\YourDir\Output.log"
```

If you intend to append to an existing `Output.log` change **`>`** to **`>>`**.